# Objective-C: Convert String to integer separated by colon

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have string value

```
NSString *str = @"12:15"
```

now how to convert it in to integer value??
i try`NSInteger i =[str integerValue];`
but it's return only 12 and i want 1215.
Please suggest.
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

A more generic approach would be to replace everything but the numeric values with an empty string like below:

```
NSString *str = @"12: a15xx";
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[^0-9]"
                                     withString:@""
                                        options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                          range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];

NSLog(@"%d", str.integerValue); // prints 1215
```

Answer (score 2):

a simple answer would be

```
NSString *str=@"12:15";
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""];
NSInteger i =[str integerValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray* arr = [@"12:15" componentsSeparatedByString: @":"];
NSString* strValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[arr objectAtIndex:0],[arr objectAtIndex:1]];

int value=(int)strValue;
```

Comment: It's better to have some explanatory text around rather than just a code answer, although this will do what the user wants it's better to try and explain it.